# Initial scrollheight of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to build a page (with Struts2 and the jQuery Struts Plugin) with alot of textareas. All of them have some Text, which I retrieve from the DB.

I use the following short snippet of code I found to dynamically adjust the height of the textares:

```
jQuery.fn.elasticArea = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        function resizeTextarea() {
            this.style.height = this.scrollHeight/2 + 'px';
            this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
        $(this).keypress(resizeTextarea)
        .keydown(resizeTextarea)
        .keyup(resizeTextarea)
        .css('overflow','hidden');
        resizeTextarea.call(this);
    });
};

$('textarea.detail').elasticArea();
```

It works wonderful as soon as I go into one of the textareas and hit a button (like Tab or Shift).

The problem is, that after initial load up, the textareas have a height of 0, because the scrollheight of each textarea is 0.

I use the following code for the textareas (inside an s:iterator:

```
<s:textarea cols="80" name="viewList[%{#viewStatus.index}].beschreibungen[%{#beschrStatus.index}].wert" cssClass="detail"/>
```

But even normal html textareas show the same behaviour.

Why the scrollheight is 0 at load up? Is there maybe a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to set a timeout to see if the scrollHeight comes after the function's call : `setTimeout(function(){$('textarea.detail').elasticArea();},200);`